How to create apache arrow from data table?
I am trying to solve problem of multiple copies created by dataframes in c# for the same thinking of creating arrow record batches directly and eliminate any extra copies.As of now tried using converting array to record batch but no luck
var allocator = new ArrowMemoryPool();

 // Create arrays for each column
 var intArray = new Int32Array.Builder(allocator).Append(1, 2, 3, 4).Build();
 var stringArray = new StringArray.Builder(allocator).Append("a", "b", "c", "d").Build();

 // Create a schema for the record batch
 var schema = new Schema(
     new Field("column1", new ArrowType.Int32()),
     new Field("column2", new ArrowType.Utf8()));

 // Create a record batch builder
 var recordBatchBuilder = new RecordBatchBuilder(allocator, schema);

 // Append the arrays to the builder`your text`
 recordBatchBuilder.Append(intArray);
 recordBatchBuilder.Append(stringArray);

 // Build the record batch
 var recordBatch = recordBatchBuilder.Build();

 // Print the number of rows and columns in the record batch
 Console.WriteLine($"Number of rows: {recordBatch.RowCount}");
 Console.WriteLine($"Number of columns: {recordBatch.ColumnCount}");

